# populate datagridview from a list and edit the list (adding)

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

I have a List

```
List <string> aList = new List<string>();
aList.Add("A,B");
aList.Add("A,C");
aList.Add("A,D");
aList.Add("A,E");
```

I have datagridview, and I want to display this list on this datagridview.

```
aDataGridView.DataSouce = aList; // Dosent seems to work.
```

When this is displayed on the datagridview I want the user to add to it from the gridview.For example:

DataGridView:
    (This column added by the user) and if user does not add anyhing, that row is excluded  from aList.
A B apple
A C banana
A D
A E

Is there anyway I can achieve this. sorry I am a beginner in C#.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest utilizing a datatable as it can ready be used as a datagridview.datasource.

Comment: A datatable is not a database it is simply as structure that can be used with a database